# How to keep same position on different resolution?

Tags: html, css

I need help. I'm creating a website on Dreamweaver. I have just started learning html and I don't know really what is the best way to position element in CSS. I'm always using this way (example):

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 185 px;
    top: 50 px;
}
```

Am I positioning element the right way? However, I want to keep the same position on different resolution.

Comment: Do u have it anywhere live ? Or jsfiddle?

Comment: IMO if you want to learn HTML/CSS/JS, then you shouldn't use Dreamweaver. Start off with a good text editor and a browser and work your way up once you've got the basics down.

Comment: I have already learnt HTML/CSS on Codecademy. I'm just using Dreamweaver to create the website. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Using position absolute should not be your default method to position elements unless you have a good reason to. Usually this is used when you need an element to break out of the document flow.
If you are just getting started I'd recommend to checkout for example https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web (it's free).

Comment: Yes, I learned HTML and CSS from codecademy, but I'm not good using "margin".

Comment: Laying out elements is probably the hardest thing to learn with css. Also the most important. Just keep trying and check out the code of websites you like. Also read up on Flexbox. (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is my go to article)

Answer (score 0):

At any given time, you should try avoiding position: absolute; and position: fixed; as much as ou can. They can be extremely handy at times, will not deny that, but most of the time you just want to go with the flow of the page.

When you create a new element, you'll naturally see everything will kind of fall in order. The text's go about the same length, they start around the same position horizontally, and the same goes for most other elements. However, when you use position: absolute or position: fixed, you pull a element out of the flow of the page, effectively creating another layer on top of your current page. This means that, while you will have loads of freedom to place it however you would like, it also means there *will* be problems if you make the window smaller than what you got right now. What happens, for example, if a mobile user visits your page?

That being said, use the already existing css-attributes as much as you can (text-align, vertical-align, even float and/or using margin's can be better) before anything else, when it comes to positioning.

EDIT: Also what **stybl** said in the comments, if you are just learning HTML and CSS, I'd not recommend using DreamWeaver either. Start off with a good text-editor and/or go to [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) instead!

Comment: Yes, I learned HTML and CSS from codecademy, but I'm not good using "margin". I really don't know what to do.

Comment: @ST_Lukas Margin can either be set as margin; or margin-left|right|top|bottom;, furthermore, it can either be set as pixels, percentage, or auto (as well as some other ones). As for how it works though, that's an usual issue. Perhaps [ŧhis](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-p8vD7Kxpd0Q/Uy2j7mt1x9I/AAAAAAAAGhU/exqNzQJYkFU/s1600/difference-between-margin-padding-css-propriety-tutorial.png) can help?

Comment: No problem, I know how margin works, but I don't know how to position some elements that I can easily position with "position: absolute".

Comment: I see. Yeah, position: absolute is easy in that way, but like I said, bad practice. You'll just have to **experiment** , that's what's so great about developing! Theres loads of material found on the internet, and there's no harm in testing as much as you like. @ST_Lukas

Comment: Ok, I will try it. So if I use "padding, margin, border", how will I be able to keep same position on different resolutions? Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: For now, you should focus on getting a decent looking and functioning site **on one resolution**. Having it work on every resolution is one of the many challenges you will face working with CSS (but remember chrome has the [built in mobile emulator](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/)). Remember the difference between using pixels and percentage though, and you should come a long way. @ST_Lukas